# Why I need to restart Tomcat Apache server every time I change/edit my java servlet code

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat8

I am coding my basic servlet programs in notepad but every time I make changes in my java file and after compiling it, I need to restart my tomcat apache to see that changes on browser. Is there any solution for this as I have to work on project and will need changes frequently.
I have tried making service automatic from services manager.

Comment: do you know what is compilation?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart Tomcat, but you will need to redeploy your application, or use a way of deployment that supports hot reloading.

Comment: Simply use a decent IDE instead of Notepad. They will do that heavy lifting for you

Comment: You can add `reloadable="true"` in your context file (e.g. the default one `conf/context.xml`). Cf. [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes).

Answer (score 0):

The changes made in Servlet/Java code will not reflect itself, we have to re-compile the Java code and again deploy the application to the Tomcat server. Only after these work server will be able to get the modified values.

If you don't want to do it manually then you can set `reloadable="true"` in the context.xml file. Now Catalina (tomcat server) will monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is very useful during application development, but it requires significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on deployed production applications. That's why the default setting for this attribute is false. You can use the Manager web application, however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand.